# the method extractContentAsDocument() is undefined for the type SOAPBody

Tags: java

I am getting this error with MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench Version: 2013 SR2
Build id: 11.0.2-20130823

I know `.extractcontentAsDocument()` exists.  Probably not in my version.

I am using `rt.jar` from

```
..\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Professional\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.u43\jre\lib
```

Do I need a different version of myEclispe?  Do I need to add the jar from another source?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outdated version of saaj-api (1.2 or lesser).

You can get a more recent jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsaajapi134jar.htm)